# ZFS never mounts my pool automatically, why?

Tags: linux, zfs

I'm running ZFS on Linux on my workstation, and have been for about two years:

```
[  273.779699] SPL: Loaded module v0.6.4.2-1~vivid
[  273.824212] ZFS: Loaded module v0.6.4.2-1~vivid, ZFS pool version 5000, ZFS filesystem version 5
[  280.179534] SPL: using hostid 0x007f0101
```

It works great, except that a couple of months ago I upgraded to Ubuntu 15.04. When I rebooted after the upgrade, the ZFS pool was not seen. At first I panicked, but when I had zpool search my devices it found the missing pool. Running "zpool import store" works fine, and everything mounts as it ought to. Until the next time I reboot.

Everytime I reboot ZFS appears to forget about my pool. However, I can't see anything obviously wrong:

```
$ sudo zpool list -Hv
store   1.30T   301G    1.00T   -       22%     22%     1.17x   ONLINE  -
        sda4    432G    135G    297G    -       31%     31%
        sdb3    896G    167G    729G    -       19%     18%
```

I also don't see anything obviously wrong in the partition tables:

```
$ sudo parted -l
Model: ATA ST500DM002-1BD14 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 500GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    File system  Name                  Flags
 1      1049kB  512MB   511MB   fat32        EFI System Partition  msftdata
 2      512MB   35.5GB  35.0GB  ext4
 4      35.5GB  500GB   465GB   zfs


Model: ATA WDC WD1002FAEX-0 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdb: 1000GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    File system     Name  Flags
 1      1049kB  10.0GB  9999MB  linux-swap(v1)
 2      10.0GB  35.0GB  25.0GB  xfs
 3      35.0GB  1000GB  965GB   zfs
```

Any guidance about where to look, or what to do would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I updated the ZFS packages this week and the problem simply vanished. It must have been a bug somewhere that got fixed. Everything is good again.

Answer (score 2):

Check `/etc/default/zfs` and make sure it's set to:

`ZFS_MOUNT='yes'
ZFS_UNMOUNT='yes'`

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem. When I reboot 'zpool list' is empty and I have to import it by hand. I have also read documentation to the effect that these are no longer necessary (although I did try them again, just to be sure.)

Answer (score 1):

Be sure to have `ubuntu-zfs`package installed, as it provides the correct pinning for the `mountall`command.
See https://github.com/zfsonlinux/pkg-zfs/wiki/Ubuntu-ZFS-mountall-FAQ-and-troubleshooting for more details

AND/OR

have a look into and change `/etc/init/zpool-import.conf`

`modprobe zfs zfs_autoimport_disable=1`

to

`modprobe zfs zfs_autoimport_disable=0`

Comment: I already had ubuntu-zfs installed. The zfs_autoimport_disable flag was set to 1, so I set it to 0 and rebooted. I still had no pools listed. I also removed the zfs module from modprobe.d list as suggested by the common mistakes. Still no joy. I'll look at some of the other suggestions later. Thanks, though!